# SOLVED - How to replace the macOS native php version to 7.4?

Tags: php, macos, ssl, webserver

**TO UPDATE THE PHP VERSION AT LOCALHOST:**

COMMENT THE FIRST LINE
--==--
#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

ADD THE SECOND LINE ON /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
--==--
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

RESTART APACHE: sudo apachectl restart

---

[SOLVED] I have tried to update macOS High Sierra native PHP version with brew and Now I got 2 php versions.

Localhost:
MySQL works perfectly!
Hello From Sites Folder!
PHP Version 7.1.33

Terminal:
php -v
PHP 7.4.8 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2020 23:46:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Installation link (SSL enabled): https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps

Comment: Did you start a web server locally? Or are you talking about PHP's local web server?

Comment: There are a lot of resources on the Internet explaining how to do this properly, including php.net. If you are still struggling, consider using MAMP

Comment: try installing brew https://brew.sh/ and then using it to install the latest version of php

Answer (score 0):

You also need web server like `nginx` to handle requests:

```
brew install nginx
sudo brew services start nginx
```

Also steps to upgrade php:

```
brew update
brew upgrade php
php -v
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Here's [a link](https://www.sylvaindurand.org/setting-up-a-nginx-web-server-on-macos/) to nice tutorial explaining in details how to set up web server on your mac